# Фон юзера, профиля

Tags: php

Вот я хочу сделать для каждого **профиля пользователей** свой фон. И вот как мне это сделать? Движок DLE

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.body.bgColor = "<?php echo $user_bg; ?>";
</script>
```

Либо даже проще...

```
<body bgColor = "<?php echo $user_bg; ?>">
```

Comment: А куда именно это вставлять и как при помощи этого ставить фон для пользователя?